# Absolute value of 2 numbers

Tags: python

I have a function defined below in which two parameters are taken and the bigger of the two numbers is used and its absolute value is calculated .

```
def max_absolute_value(int1, int2):

 value = 0

 if (int1 >= int2):
    value = int1
 else:
    value = int2
    
    if value <= 0:
        return value * -1
    return value * 1

result = max_absolute_value(3, -5)
print(result)
```

The above should return `5` as the absolute value of -5 is higher than 3, however, when I run the function it returns `None`.

Comment: You have problem in your code indentation. Also the logic of your code is not correct. Better to use `abs()` and `max()`

Comment: use the math.abs function

Answer (score 2):

May be use something like this -

```
def max_absolute_value(int1,int2):
    return max(abs(int1), abs(int2))
```

Now with your code the `None` is returned because in the `if` block there is no return. You may have meant -

```
def max_absolute_value(int1,int2):

 value = 0

 if (int1 >= int2):
    value = int1
 else:
    value = int2
    
 if value <= 0:
    return value * -1
 return value * 1
```

Still there is some logic issue in your code. In the `if` condition -5 will be less than 3. So your code will return absolute value of that i.e. is 3. Which is wrong. I think the first solution will be better for you.

Comment: `abs` takes only one argument.

Comment: @blhsing, you are right. Made that blunder trying to post the answer fast

Answer (score 0):

It is giving absolute value of "3" instead of absolute value of "-5" as 3 > -5
You must first take absolute value of both the numbers and then compare them

```
def absolute_value(a):
    if a <= 0:
        return a * -1
    return a * 1

def max_absolute_value(int1,int2):
    if absolute_value(int1) >= absolute_value(int2):
        return absolute_value(int1)
    return absolute_value(int2)
```

A simpler approach for getting absolute value is to directly use the function `abs()`, which returns the absolute value of the number.

```
def max_absolute_value(int1,int2):
    if abs(int1) >= abs(int2):
        return abs(int1)
    return abs(int2)
```

Using the `max()` function will return a bigger value of the two.
So, an even shortened form will be:

```
def max_absolute_value(int1,int2):
    return max(abs(int1, int2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a one-liner including `max(...)`, `abs(...)` and `map(...)`:

```
def max_absolute_value(int1, int2):
    return max(map(abs, [int1, int2]))


result = max_absolute_value(-3, -5)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def max_absolute_value(int1,int2):
    return max(abs(int1),abs(int2))

result = max_absolute_value(3,-5)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. The problem lies with the indentation level of your code. The indentation of 1st and 2nd if...else loop must match. Then it will work as expected. It should look like this-

```
def max_absolute_value(int1,int2):

 value = 0

 if (int1 >= int2):
    value = int1
 else:
    value = int2
    
 if value <= 0:
    return value * -1
 else:
    return value * 1

result = max_absolute_value(3,-5)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_absolute_value(int1,int2):
    return int1 if abs(int1) > abs(int2) else int2

result = max_absolute_value(3,-5)
print(result)
```

Comment: what does this code do and how does it answer the question?